# Pointer Reallocation and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory, polymorphism

I am currently studying polymorphism and its relation to pointers in C++. While I understand how static and dynamic allocation relate to polymorphism, there is one case that has confused me.

```
class Human
{
    public:
        virtual void talk();
};

void Human::talk(){ cout << "oink oink" << endl; }

class Doctor : public Human
{
    public:
        virtual void talk();
};

void Doctor::talk(){ cout << "ouaf ouaf" << endl; }


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Human h = Doctor();
    Human* p = new Doctor();

    delete p;
    p = &h;
    p->talk();

}
```

What I don't understand is why `p->speak()` outputs `oink oink` instead of `ouaf ouaf`. Is it because p is being reallocated to a location on the stack instead of the heap? If p can be reallocated, why isn't it just pointing to the address of `h` and deciding to call the `talk()` function in `Doctor` at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line Human h = Doctor(); First h is created then Doctor object is created and then copy constructor of human is called. H is declared as Human so it will remain human after copy construction.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Human
{
    public:
        virtual void talk();
        Human()
        {
            cout<<"Human"<<endl;
        }
        Human(const Human & h)
        {
            cout<<"Copy Human"<<endl;
        }
};

void Human::talk(){ cout << "oink oink" << endl; }

class Doctor : public Human
{
    public:
        virtual void talk();
        Doctor()
        {
            cout<<"Doctor"<<endl;
        }
        Doctor(const Human & h)
        {
            cout<<"Copy Doctor"<<endl;
        }
};

void Doctor::talk(){ cout << "ouaf ouaf" << endl; }


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Human h = Doctor();
    Human* p = new Doctor();

    delete p;
    p = &h;
    p->talk();

}
```

Comment: If you did `int j; j=0.5;` would you expect `j` to have any type other than `int`?

Comment: No i dont expect j to ahve any type other than int.I unsersatnd your point sir so i edited my answer.

Comment: My comment was more aimed at the OP to explain to him why his expectation is unreasonable.